# Wordpress - Shorten Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

On my forum **(made in WordPress)** I let users add copy to clipboard buttons so they can make code easier to copy. I am **using a plugin for this** meaning that when you are posting something on the forum and type this then it will make a copy to clipboard button:

```
[pw-clippy caption="Copy"]Text to Copy goes here[/pw-clippy]
```

I don't really like users having to use the name of the plugin **'pw-clippy'** when making these buttons so I am wondering if I can shorten it so instead you type something like:

```
[copytoclip caption="Copy"]Text to Copy goes here[/copytoclip]
```

**or this would also be fine:**

```
[copytoclip]Text to Copy goes here[/copytoclip]
```

This may have an easy solution but I am fairly new to WordPress and would like to learn more.

**Thanks for any help.**

**Note: I am not sure if it is called shortcode but any knowledge on it would be appreciated :D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but here goes:

```
function copytoclip_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ){
    return do_shortcode('[pw-clippy caption="Copy"]' . $content . '[/pw-clippy]');
}

add_shortcode( 'copytoclip', 'copytoclip_shortcode' );
```

Add this to `functions.php`, or even better as a standalone plugin file in your `wp-content/plugins/` directory.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get time.